# Load bootstrap forms from select page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a register form. I just need to load bootstrap form in same page behind the select menu when someone click something from select menu. Should I hide form until someone click that item in select menu right?

**This is my code.**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control menu">
        <option>Select category*</option>
        <option>Apartment</option>
        <option>Lands</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need to load this form someone click **Apartment** in the menu.

```
<form>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Size(sqft)">
                        /div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No of bedrooms">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="No of bathrooms">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I tried play with this code. But it redirect to another pages.

```
<script>
   $('select.menu').change(function(e){
      // this function runs when a user selects an option from a <select> element
      window.location.href = $("select.menu option:selected").attr('value');
   });
</script>
```

What method do I need to follow?

Comment: Is your `form` is in the same HTML page? And you want to show the form when **appartment is selected from dropdown select box.**

Comment: Yes. You got that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q288ru4o/):

I gave your wrapper of your apartment an id `<div class="col-md-12" id="apartment">`.

So I added following jQuery to toggle your html of your apartment:

```
$('select.menu').change(function(){
  // this function runs when a user selects an option from a <select> element
  switch($(this).find("option:selected").prop('value')) {
    case '1': $('#apartment').show(); break;
    default: $('#apartment').hide(); break;
  }
});
```

And don't forget to hide your `#apartment`:

```
#apartment {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is great! You made my day. How can I add multiple forms? Let's say I need to show another form by clicking lands from select menu?

Comment: Let's say you want to show 'lands'. Put `lands` as id in your html and add this line in the switch function: 
`case '2': $('#lands').show(); break;` and your default have to look like this `default: $('#apartment').hide(); $('#lands').hide(); break;`.

Comment: It's working but there is a problem. If I choose apartment it shows it's form. Then if I choose lands, apartment form couldn't hide. It will display all two forms.

Comment: Then you have to hide apartment in "case 2" aswell.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But imagine if I have 5 or 6 forms. I have to repeat same codes over and over again. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: With every change you could first hide all of your subforms. Then you only show the selected one. This can be easily done by adding a class to your subforms like `<div class="col-md-12 subform" id="apartment">`. So you could put `$('.subform').hide();` in the first line of your change function.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` will redirect you to the new page. You can just hide your form before user make a select change or get it dynamically with `jQuery.load()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your HTML,

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control menu">
    <option>Select category*</option>
    <option>Apartment</option>
    <option>Lands</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

by default let the form is in `display:none`.

Jquery,

```
<script>
   $('select.menu').change(function(e){
      // this function runs when a user selects an option from a <select> element
      window.location.href = $("select.menu option:selected").attr('value');

     if($(this).val == "Apartment"){
        $('form').show();
     }else{
        $('form').hide();
     }
  });
</script>
```